# PrettyTable format title

Tags: python, plot, prettytable

I want to format a title for prettytable with values but I can't.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable


name = "table 1"
table = PrettyTable()
owntitle  = "table name is {}".format(str(name))
table.title = owntitle 
table.field_names = ['Experiment', 'Value']
table.add_row(['bla', 3.14])
table.add_row(['baz', 42.0])

print(table)
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your code with

```
table.title = owntitle
```

also install [PTable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PTable) before executing your code.

```
pip install PTable
```

Comment: its a mistake.. I change it in the Q.

Comment: table.title = owntitle - that was the original line

Comment: what is the output your are getting with above code?

Comment: the table with no title

Comment: install PTable and then execute your code, see updated answer.

Comment: just installing and leaving the code as it is  - didnt work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159599/discussion-between-vipin-kumar-and-anna).